# htaccess routes

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible to write a htaccess file which will take a URL

`/some-new-name` and direct to the actual page `/file-name.php`

All the content is created in the page `/file-name.php` but I want the user to type `/some-new-name` and be taken to that page

Also is it possible to force the `/some-new-name` to display if a user was to click `/file-name.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following code to do that:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from file-name.php to /some-new-name
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\sfile-name\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ some-new-name [R=301,L,NC]

# internal redirect from /some-new-name to file-name.php
RewriteRule ^some-new-name$ file-name.php [L,NC]
```